# Conditional cell blacking

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet where there's initially 75 rows and 24 columns.  Row 1 has a title of a game in it, and row 2 is blank.  Then rows 3-72 and columns 2-24 are blacked out.

And when either a cell is blank for "don't own" or "1" for "own" is entered in a cell in row 2, the entire column becomes accessible.  Then when the column is accessible, information in the cells is shown.

So if row 2 is blank, it will be http://prntscr.com/k6lalm.  And if there is a "1" in a cell(s) in row 2, it will be http://prntscr.com/k6lbcl. (Yes, I'm making a spreadsheet for Pokémon.)

Not sure how I would go about doing a conditional format for it or using an IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is what you want but suggest that if you want to 'overlay' or 'peel off' black fill from the 'data' part of each column according to whether or not the column is populated with `1` in Row 2, then select the body of your 'data' (starting from B3), clear an existing CF from the range and apply a *Custom formula is* of :

```
=B$2<>1
```

and select black fill. The *Apply to range* should be B3:X35.

Adding or clearing a `1` in Row2 should then remove or add CF black fill over the  the relevant part of the relevant column. On removal of the CF fill whatever 'standard' fill (could be black) applied to the cell should be displayed.